# Setting active tab in ASP.NET Ajax TabContainer causes entire container to disappear

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I have an ASP.NET page that uses the [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit TabContainer](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx). In the `Page_Load` event, I am hiding some of the tabs based on the data given to the page. I then want to make one of the tabs active based on the value of an (optional) query string parameter.

So I have:

```
protected void Page_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if ( !this.IsPostBack )
    {
        // Tabs with no data are hidden in here
        LoadDataIntoTabs();

        PreselectCorrectTab();
    }
}

private void PreselectCorrectTab ()
{
    if ( ctlTabContainer.Visible )
    {
        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( Request.QueryString[ "tabIndex" ] ) )
        {
            int tabIndex = 0;

            if ( int.TryParse( Request.QueryString[ "tabIndex" ], out tabIndex ) )
            {
                if ( ( ctlTabContainer.Tabs.Count > tabIndex ) && ctlTabContainer.Tabs[ tabIndex ].Visible )
                {
                    ctlTabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = tabIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I hit the page with the `tabIndex` query string parameter set, the entire tab container disappears.

The strange thing is that if I change `LoadDataIntoTabs()` to **not** hide tabs that contain no data, everything works as you would expect (i.e. the correct tab is selected when the page renders).

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

As requested, here are more details:

```
private void LoadDataIntoTabs ()
{
    LoadPendingWidgetsTab();
    LoadDataIntoTab2();
    LoadDataIntoTab3();
    // etc...
}

private void LoadPendingWidgetsTab ()
{
    IList<Widget> pendingWidgets = GetAllPendingWidgets();

    if ( ( pendingWidgets != null ) && ( pendingWidgets.Count > 0 ) )
    {
        tbpPendingWidgets.Visible = true;
        tbpPendingWidgets.HeaderText = String.Format( "Pending Widgets ({0})", pendingWidgets.Count );

        grdPendingWidgets.DataSource = pendingWidgets;
        grdPendingWidgets.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        tbpPendingWidgets.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for LoadDataIntoTabs(), it sounds like the issue is in there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set the desired tab via ActiveTab like:

`ctlTabContainer.ActiveTab = tbpPendingWidgets;`

If you set the first tab to `Visible=false` then you have to set the next visible tab page via ActiveTab.

I'am using the AjaxControlToolkit Release 30930 (September 2009).

Comment: This fixed my issue. It looks like if your 'ActiveTab' is made invisible it makes the whole tab container hidden.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
Manually resetting the index, the visibility and the active tab.

```
 tabcontainer.ActiveTab = tabname
 tabcontainer.Visible = True
 tabcontainer.ActiveTabIndex = 2
```

In another situation where I was not trying to set the active tab, I had to reset  `tabcontainer.ActiveTabIndex = 0`.

So I put the two together and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple and worked perfectly,try this

assign the tab index for every tab that are used in your tab container  like....

then `<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">`

`<cc1:TabPanel ID="tab1" runat="server" TabIndex="0">`
//your panel
`</cc1:TabPanel>`
`<cc1:TabPanel ID="tab2" runat="server" TabIndex="1">`
//your panel
`</cc1:TabPanel>`

`</cc1:TabContainer>`

write this code in cs page

`TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 1;`